# Как найти и скачать фото в браузере на Python

Tags: python, парсер, webbrowser

Мне необходимо найти и скачать фото по метке на python. Вот что я нашёл:

```
import webbrowser
key = 'яблоко'
webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://www.google.ru/search?q=' + key + '&newwindow=1&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X')
```

что делать дальше?

Comment: Дальше надо писать оставшийся код.

Answer (score 4):

Через [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#browser-controller-objects) никак не получится -- он умеет только открывать ссылки.

---

Для этой задачи используйте `selenium`, его придется установить:

```
pip install selenium
```

И [настраивать чтобы работал](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/1ed16057882ba10e60b1001dec73b27d9153396e/selenium__examples/hello_world.py#L18) для указанного браузера, например `Firefox`.

---

**UPD.**

Меня этот вопрос увлек и пока разбирался как из результата поиска гугла вытащить картинки получился [пример выгрузки первой картинки](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d3a9a036aafbcfa2a3d48092adf0a4a160dd3e49/selenium__examples/google_search__get_first_image.py#L21) из результата поиска:

```
from base64 import b64decode

# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver


key = 'яблоко'
url = f'https://www.google.ru/search?q={key}&newwindow=1&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # seconds
driver.get(url)

# Поиск первой картинки
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[starts-with(@src, "data:image/jpeg;base64,")]')

src = img.get_attribute('src')
src = src.split('data:image/jpeg;base64,')[1]

img_data = b64decode(src)

with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img_data)

# Делаем скриншот результата
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')

driver.quit()
```

Фишка в том, что картинки хранятся в `img@src` как `base64`.

Результат:

`screenshot.png`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`img.jpg`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: полезная [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361742/download-image-with-selenium-python)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @fauX, пожалуйста, а [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)